# How to group data into charts in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, charts, crystal-reports

I have prepared data that describe usage (in percentages) of certain machines over time. Basically, I have a table with machines and for each there are dates with corresponding percentage values. I can easily visualize this in a line graph where there is the time on the x axis and the percentages on the y axis. The particular lines will represent the machines - their usage over time.

The problem comes when the machines will be divided into several groups and I will need to make a chart separately for the machines in each group. Each chart should be on a separate page.

In the table with my data the group is assigned for each machine. So I need to group the table by the machine group. This is easy to do with just tables, but how to make several charts based on the machine groups each on a separate page?

Comment: Any changes you have made, It is always depend the Query structure from only yours. Graph is just waiting on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I've come up with the specific solution to the given problem that worked for me.

I made the line graph of the data this way: *On change of* **Time** and **Machine** *Show* **Usage**.

Then I created *Grouping by* **Machine Groups** and inside *Group Header* section I put the graph.

Finally I've put *New Page After* into *Group Footer* (selected via *Section Expert*).

And that's it, this way I've created several graphs each on a seperate page that show usage over time of groups of machines.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Crystal Reports since before Windows 95.  It has not much changed since then.  (Thus it has not enhanced much either).  Crystal has many limitations in how it handles data.  To side step this and get Crystal to do everything you want I concluded many years ago.  It is best to do something referred to as "Data Shaping" before the data gets into Crystal.  I prefer to do this with stored procedures but you can manually modify the crystal select sql code.  It is better to do this with a stored procedure so you can run the database code and insure the data is as desired before you deal with crystal reports.

Back into your problem.  Create a data set that allows you to do what you want to do with crystal.  Then make a stored procedure that modifies the data for what Crystal needs to make the output you desire.

One example of this is to add a column for a page break in the Sql.  Then you tell Crystal to page break on a change in the new column of data you created in the stored procedure outside of crystal.

Crystal is a powerful tool but has a lot of limitations and it basically expects data to be in a certain format.  It does not do the transformation needed but stored procedures do let you do the transformation on the fly.

Combine stored procedure data shaping (transformation) with crystal and you have a reporting tool that is arguably best on the market if you target a paper output.  (Crystal doesn't do web well).

Comment: If you want more help post something that explains you data structure.  With the high level question posted it is hard to get more specific.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've dealt with this my own way (see my answer). By the way I'm using stored procedures to prepare the data, that's how I got the table in the first place. The problem was how to get the data inside the graphs the way I wanted them.